# $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1+x^{2}}{(1+|x-y|)^{n}} dx<\infty $ for some large $n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

Fix $y\in \mathbb R.$

Define, $$I(y)=\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1+x^{2}}{(1+|x-y|)^{n}} dx.$$

**My Question is**: Can we show that $I(y)<\infty$ for some large $n\in \mathbb N$ ? If yes, what is a value of $I(y);$ is it true that, $\int_{\mathbb R} |I(y)| dy <\infty$ ?

Answer (score 5):

The change of variables $x\leftarrow y+t$ allows us to conclude that the integral converges if and only if $n>3$. Moreover, it shows that
$$I(y)=2\int_0^\infty\frac{1+t^2}{(1+t)^n}dt+2y^2\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(1+t)^n}$$
This can be calculated explicitly:
$$
I(y)=2\left(\frac{1}{n-3}-\frac{1}{n-2}+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)+\frac{2y^2}{n-1}
$$
and clearly, $\int_{\mathbb{R}}I(y)dy=+\infty$ in this case